# Prove the equation has unique class of solutions

Tags: inequality, functional-equations

Find the solutions of equation:
$$
x^y + y^x = 1 + xy \quad x,y \in \mathbb{R} \quad x,y >0
$$

**My quest**

First, $x=1$ or $y=1$ gives us obvious solutions, so let's suppose $x \not =1$ and $y \not= 1$.

Using Bernoulli's inequality I was able to show the inequality:
$$
x^y + y^x > 1 + xy \quad \forall x,y>0 \quad and \quad (x-1)(y-1) \gt 0
$$
Therefore there is no solution with $x,y\gt1$ or $x,y\lt1$.

My goal is to show that there is no solution having $x \not =1$ and $y \not= 1$ and the only case I was not able to cover is $(x-1)(y-1)<0$.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Just a note: if either $x$ or $y$ is $1$ then the other variable can be every positive real number and it solves the equation. Therefore you can assume $x≠1$ AND $y≠1$.

Comment: believable: plot graphs of $x^y + y^x -xy = 101/100$ and $x^y + y^x -xy = 99/100.$

Comment: @user109899 I've re-written the question for more clarity. Thanks for your note

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got it:

Suppose $x > 1, y < 1$. Then, using Bernoulli's inequality:
$$
x^y = (1 + (x - 1))^y < 1 + y(x -1)
$$
Therefore
$$
x^y + y^x < 1 + y(x -1) + y^x= 1 + xy -y + y^x < 1 + xy
$$
because:  $y^x<y$

Comment: Beautiful! '+1'

Answer (score 1):

you have given no source and no indication of your background. The conclusion that the solution set is the lines (in the first quadrant only) $y=1$ and $x=1$ seems quite likely given these plots; if you know multivariable calculus this gives some directions to pursue.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a rather elementary solution

Comment: I think I got the answer, I just post it

Answer (score -4):

By the fundamental theorem on solutions to non linear equations, there are exactly n - 1 solutions, where n is the number of variables

Comment: Thank you for a good laugh :)

Comment: Sorry, but your  fundamental theorem on solutions to non linear equations differ from main

Comment: @Servaes there is no need to offend new users ;)

Comment: @user109899 Theoretically true, but this automatic reaction/admonestation seems spectacularly ill-adapted to the character at hand.

Comment: @Servaes Cheers mate.